# Looping Unity 3D animation. The character loops in one position in the animation itself

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vul4F.png)I start the scene, the Idle position works. I'm running, the Run animation is working. But as soon as I have to jump, the devil knows what begins. I jump from a place and the character jumps, but without animation and in the Idle state, and after the first jump I can't even jump anymore. But I checked, and it seems that the JumpFromIdle animation does not go into Idle, but loops, the same with JumpFromRun. Help!!!! I've wasted my day on this. I'll leave the code and screenshot below. Here is the link to the screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ycQOkUC_4EPjqz7Z5iRd9fRdAMR5QUdH/view?usp=sharing.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Animator _animator;

    public float speed = 5.0f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 5.0f; // The speed of the smooth rotation of the player
    public float jumpForce = 8.0f;
    private bool isGrounded;
    private CharacterController _controller;
    private Vector3 _moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    private Quaternion targetRotation;

    private bool isJumping = false;
    private bool isDancing = false;

    void Start()
    {
        _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = _controller.isGrounded;

        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        // Determining the direction of the player's movement
        Vector3 inputDirection = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput);

        // The player's turn in the direction of movement
        if (inputDirection != Vector3.zero)
        {
            targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(inputDirection);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        // Player Movement
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            _moveDirection = transform.forward * inputDirection.magnitude * speed;

            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && !isJumping)
            {
                _moveDirection.y = jumpForce;

                // Jump Animation
                _animator.SetBool("JumpFromIdle", true);


                // If the player is running, turn on the "Jump from Run" animation
                if (inputDirection.magnitude > 0.1f)
                {
                    _animator.SetBool("JumpFromRun", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    _animator.SetBool("JumpFromRun", false);
                    _animator.SetBool("JumpFromIdle", false);
                }

                isJumping = true;
                StopDance();
            }

            if (inputDirection.magnitude > 0.1f) // Stopping the animation of the dance while moving
            {
                StopDance();
            }

            if (Input.GetKey("1"))
            {
                StartDance();
            }
            else
            {
                StopDance();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            StopDance(); // Stopping the animation of the dance when jumping
        }

        // Animation "Run"
        if (inputDirection.magnitude > 0.1f)
        {
            _animator.SetBool("Run", true);
        }
        else
        {
            _animator.SetBool("Run", false);
        }

        // Gravity
        _moveDirection.y -= 9.8f * Time.deltaTime;

        // Movement using the Character Controller
        _controller.Move(_moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    private void StartDance()
    {
        if (!isDancing)
        {
            _animator.SetBool("Dancing", true);
            isDancing = true;
        }
    }

    private void StopDance()
    {
        if (isDancing)
        {
            _animator.SetBool("Dancing", false);
            isDancing = false;
        }
    }

    // Processing of the jump animation end event
    public void OnJumpAnimationEnd()
    {
        // Reset the jump flag and animation parameters "Jump from Run" and "Jump from Idle"
        isJumping = false;
        _animator.SetBool("JumpFromRun", false);
        _animator.SetBool("JumpFromIdle", false);
    }
}
```

I tried changing branches in Animator. I stretched the arrow through JumpFromRun in Idle and when running, the character jumps with two animations, this is not correct, and jumps as long as I run. I changed everything in the script, did everything through separate functions and nothing happened.